# IN C# from foreach to for loop for datagridview combobox column

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

The below is my code

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBoxCell = (row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell);
                        foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            string customerId = drow[0].ToString();
                            comboBoxCell.Items.Add(drow[1]);

                            if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == customerId)
                            {
                                comboBoxCell.Value = drow[1];
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

i want to change the foreach loop into for loop

like

```
  (dataGridView1.Columns[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = dt;

            for (int i = 0; i <dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
               dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dt; 
            }
```

but it is not showing my required result
Please any suggestion
Regards

Comment: Why do you need a loop? dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: Because i am papulating the column with column name

Comment: You can use an "AS" in the query to change name.  SELECT COLUMN_A as ABC

Comment: please write if you can query or i show you the query @jdweng
`
string sqlquery = @"select mid,name,nic from SalesMan where isblocked = 0 order by name asc ";

`

Comment: string sqlquery = @"select mid as 'Middle Name',name as 'First Name',nic as 'NICK NAME' from SalesMan where isblocked = 0 order by name asc ";

Comment: How to papulate it in for loop

Comment: You do not need for loop.  Use : dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: I think you didn't read my question properly. I said i have combobox in second field. I need to change the loop from foreach to for loop this is my question @jdweng

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) { DataRow drow = dt.Rows[i]; }